# OSX Lion and NAS problems

Tags: nas, osx-lion

I have a NAS LACIE 2Tb BigDisk server.

I can't connect to the disk as I get the following error:

[image]

This didn't happen in Snow Leopard. How can I solve this?

Comment: Also a problem with QNAP firmware 3.4.4 (which was released after Lion gone wild!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mac OS X Lion doesn't support the authentication DHCAST128 anymore (for security reasons apparently).

To reactivate it, you need to enter the following lines of code in Terminal:

```
sudo chmod o+w /Library/Preferences
defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.AppleShareClient afp_host_prefs_version -int 1
```

After a restart, you should try to connect to the NAS through an AFP-Share (which will give you an Error Message again). A new connection profile should now have appeared in your "/Library/Preferences". Now you only need to enter the following commands to enable DHCAST128 support:

```
sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.AppleShareClient afp_disabled_uams -array "Cleartxt Passwrd" "MS2.0" "2-Way Randnum exchange"
sudo chmod o-w /Library/Preferences
```

After another restart, the NAS connection should work.

In case you want to desactive DHCAST128 autentication again you need to type the following line:

```
sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.AppleShareClient afp_disabled_uams -array-add "DHCAST128"
```